# How to open an image in Python

Tags: image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am new to python. I am learning how to add images to my `Tkinter` file. However, when I try to run the following code, the interpreter returns the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: `lee.jpg`

I hypothesize that I need a more specific path and have already ensured that both the file and image are in the same folder. Any explanations would be appreciated.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image

    #Main Window
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Join")
    window.geometry("800x600")
    window.configure(background='white')

    path = "lee.jpg" # I believe this is causing issues

    #Makes image Tkinter-compatible
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))


    panel = Label(window, image=img)


    panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

    #Start
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple and can be achieved with the below:

```
from tkinter import * #imports tkinter

root = Tk() #establishes root as the Tk window

image = PhotoImage(file="lee.jpg") #imports image from file
label = Label(root, image=image) #creates a Label object containing the image

label.pack() #packs the Label into the Tk window

root.mainloop() #starts event loop
```

This is probably the simplest way to achieve the desired result.

If you're new to Python I would suggest a free tutorial rather than Stack Overflow, and if you're new to tKinter then http://effbot.org/tkinterbook is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The Tkinter website looks like it will be a great help. However, the console still returns the same error: couldn't open "lee.jpg": no such file or directory. Are my supposed to create a new folder with only the code and files in it?

Comment: No, as long as there is a file name "lee.jpg" in the same folder as the script and the file can be read the above script will open the image

Answer (score 0):

you can use pillow module

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(r'path/to/file.png')
img.show()
```

i hope this helps....